# Calculated Value For Google Form Item Not Refreshing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have been using the script suggested by Mogsdad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069107/getting-a-google-form-script-generated-email-to-pipe-data-into-reponse-sheet/27000505#27000505). I have hit a bit of a brick wall trying to use the timestamp as per my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099986/compare-timestamp-in-two-different-formats-gas).

So, my approach now is to try to get a unique ID in to the form before submission so that I can use it in the form response feedback in to the sheet. I am try to force a list item to have a selection of one value via the below script -

```
function updateForm(){
  // a way to get the items from the form
  var form = FormApp.openById("1t4NG2KYk09YiVzeVypWKpYTiWN97VuLBibafKbKfzP4");
  var seqList = form.getItemById(1050085080).asListItem();
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.valueOf();
  seqList.setChoiceValues([n]);
}
```

While this is indeed creating a unique value, and putting it on the form response sheet, when I go in to the form to create a new submission, the same ID number is still there. Any ideas on how I force that value to be recalculated each time the form is brought up ?

Comment: who calls updateForm? you need to put it in onFormSubmit (google that) so it gets called every time someone submits a response.

Comment: Thanks Zig. Yes I tried putting it in on FormSubmit as well. If you follow the first link I included in my question you will see that the script there is trying to use a unique value from the form to embed in the 'approval' mail so that the response can be written back to the original sheet via an index lookup. The original script tries to use the timestamp, but as per my second link this has so far not worked due to timing of the script. I am trying to come up with something other than the timestamp to use as a 'key' to help locate where the approval response should be put in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the very important thing. It's called like a pre-form action or a trigger or an automate action. You can't do that.

You need create your own Form to manage your data. Look at [I need to create a Google form to check if data being entered already exists in sheet](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/docs/UyLQ-09m6E4)

Cheers!

Comment: Its not necesary to have what you mention since the same can be done from onFormSubmit